# postfix/dovecot temporary failure

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

Incoming mail gets deferred and never delivered. I have no idea what I'm missing as I usually only setup outbound relays. Any direction here would be greatly appreciated.

Specific log

```
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/pipe[2241]: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G: to=<not4you@toknowl.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.12, delays=0.05/0.03/0/0.04, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

Full log

```
Sep 19 19:55:33 mybox postfix/postscreen[2212]: CONNECT from [209.85.208.48]:45757 to [1.2.3.4]:25
Sep 19 19:55:39 mybox postfix/postscreen[2212]: PASS NEW [209.85.208.48]:45757
Sep 19 19:55:39 mybox postfix/smtpd[2217]: connect from mail-ed1-f48.google.com[209.85.208.48]
Sep 19 19:55:39 mybox postfix/smtpd[2217]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ed1-f48.google.com[209.85.208.48]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (4096 bits) server-digest SHA256
Sep 19 19:55:40 mybox policyd-spf[2227]: prepend Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=209.85.208.48; helo=mail-ed1-f48.google.com; envelope-from=youdontknow@gmail.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Sep 19 19:55:40 mybox postfix/smtpd[2217]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-ed1-f48.google.com[209.85.208.48]
Sep 19 19:55:40 mybox postfix/10025/smtpd[2233]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/10025/smtpd[2233]: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/cleanup[2234]: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G: message-id=<CA+rp0PmijFeCmUbx=XJ69+8=9oWqGoe-uqoqOGB4HmME1jEsDw@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/10025/smtpd[2233]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/qmgr[1562]: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G: from=<youdontknow@gmail.com>, size=3426, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox amavis[1981]: (01981-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [209.85.208.48]:45757 [209.85.208.48] ESMTP/ESMTP <youdontknow@gmail.com> -> <not4you@toknowl.com>, (ESMTPS://[209.85.208.48]:45757), Message-ID: <CA+rp0PmijFeCmUbx=XJ69+8=9oWqGoe-uqoqOGB4HmME1jEsDw@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: r-nokkJE-MuE, b: rXp-iUffe, Hits: -0.199, size: 2826, queued_as: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G, Subject: "AV Scanner", From: <youdontknow@gmail.com> (dkim:AUTHOR), helo=mail-ed1-f48.google.com, Tests: [DKIM_SIGNED=0.1,DKIM_VALID=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_EF=-0.1,FREEMAIL_FROM=0.001,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2=-0.001,SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001,SPF_PASS=-0.001], autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no, autolearnscore=-0.198, dkim_i=@gmail.com, dkim_sd=20210112:gmail.com, 789 ms
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/smtpd[2217]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G; from=<youdontknow@gmail.com> to=<not4you@toknowl.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ed1-f48.google.com>
Sep 19 19:55:41 mybox postfix/pipe[2241]: 4MWb5900Hbz3y2G: to=<not4you@toknowl.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.12, delays=0.05/0.03/0/0.04, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Sep 19 19:56:12 mybox postfix/smtpd[2217]: disconnect from mail-ed1-f48.google.com[209.85.208.48] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
```

dovecot.conf

```
    root@mybox:~# cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf     
    listen = * [::]
    mail_plugins = quota mailbox_alias acl mail_log notify
    protocols = pop3 imap sieve lmtp
    mail_uid = 2000
    mail_gid = 2000
    first_valid_uid = 2000
    last_valid_uid = 2000
    syslog_facility = local5
    ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl = required
    verbose_ssl = no
    ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/tls.crt
    ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/tls.key
    ssl_dh = </etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem
    ssl_cipher_list = EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
    disable_plaintext_auth = yes
    mail_location = maildir:%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%Lh/Maildir/
    auth_mechanisms = PLAIN LOGIN
    login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c %k session=<%{session}>
    deliver_log_format = from=%{from}, envelope_sender=%{from_envelope}, subject=%{subject}, msgid=%m, size=%{size}, delivery_time=%{delivery_time}ms, %$
    service auth {
        unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
            user = postfix
            group = postfix
            mode = 0666
        }
        unix_listener auth-master {
            user = vmail
            group = vmail
            mode = 0666
        }
        unix_listener auth-userdb {
            user = vmail
            group = vmail
            mode = 0660
        }
    }
    service lmtp {
        user = vmail
    
        process_min_avail = 5
    
        executable = lmtp -L
    
        unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
            user = postfix
            group = postfix
            mode = 0600
        }
        inet_listener lmtp {
    
            address = 127.0.0.1
            port = 24
        }
    }
    userdb {
        args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
        driver = sql
    }
    passdb {
        args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
        driver = sql
    }
    auth_master_user_separator = *
    passdb {
        driver = passwd-file
        args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-master-users
        master = yes
    }
    plugin {
    
        quota = dict:user::proxy::quotadict
        quota_warning = storage=100%% quota-warning 100 %u
        quota_warning2 = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
        quota_warning3 = storage=90%% quota-warning 90 %u
        quota_warning4 = storage=85%% quota-warning 85 %u
        quota_grace = 10%%
        quota_status_success = DUNNO
        quota_status_nouser = DUNNO
        quota_status_overquota = "552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full"
        acl = vfile
        acl_shared_dict = proxy::acl
        sieve_dir = ~/sieve
        sieve = ~/sieve/dovecot.sieve
        sieve_global_dir = /var/vmail/sieve
        sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/dovecot.sieve
        sieve_max_redirects = 30
        sieve_vacation_send_from_recipient = yes
        mailbox_alias_old = Sent
        mailbox_alias_new = Sent Messages
        mailbox_alias_old2 = Sent
        mailbox_alias_new2 = Sent Items
        mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge copy mailbox_create mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
        mail_log_fields = uid box msgid size from subject flags
        last_login_dict = proxy::lastlogin
        last_login_key = last-login/%s/%u/%d
    }
    service stats {
        fifo_listener stats-mail {
            user = vmail
            mode = 0644
        }
        unix_listener stats-writer {
            user = vmail
            group = vmail
            mode = 0660
        }
        inet_listener {
            address = 127.0.0.1
            port = 24242
        }
    }
    service quota-warning {
        executable = script /usr/local/bin/dovecot-quota-warning.sh
        unix_listener quota-warning {
            user = vmail
            group = vmail
            mode = 0660
        }
    }
    service quota-status {
    
        executable = quota-status -p postfix
        client_limit = 1
        inet_listener {
            address = 127.0.0.1
            port = 12340
        }
    }
    service dict {
        unix_listener dict {
            mode = 0660
            user = vmail
            group = vmail
        }
    }
    dict {
        quotadict = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-used-quota.conf
        acl = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-share-folder.conf
        lastlogin = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-last-login.conf
    }
    protocol lda {
        mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
        lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
        lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
    }
    protocol lmtp {
    
        mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
        lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox = yes
        recipient_delimiter = +
    }
    protocol imap {
        mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_quota imap_acl last_login
        imap_client_workarounds = tb-extra-mailbox-sep
        mail_max_userip_connections = 30
    }
    protocol pop3 {
        mail_plugins = $mail_plugins last_login
        pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
        pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
        mail_max_userip_connections = 30
    }
    service imap-login {
        service_count = 1
        process_limit = 500
    }
    service pop3-login {
        service_count = 1
    }
    service managesieve-login {
        inet_listener sieve {
            address = 127.0.0.1
            port = 4190
        }
    }
    namespace {
        type = private
        separator = /
        prefix =
        inbox = yes
        mailbox Sent {
            auto = subscribe
            special_use = \Sent
        }
        mailbox "Sent Messages" {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Sent
        }
        mailbox "Sent Items" {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Sent
        }
        mailbox Drafts {
            auto = subscribe
            special_use = \Drafts
        }
        mailbox Trash {
            auto = subscribe
            special_use = \Trash
        }
        mailbox "Deleted Messages" {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Trash
        }
        mailbox Junk {
            auto = subscribe
            special_use = \Junk
        }
        mailbox Spam {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Junk
        }
        mailbox "Junk E-mail" {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Junk
        }
        mailbox Archive {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Archive
        }
        mailbox Archives {
            auto = no
            special_use = \Archive
        }
    }
    namespace {
        type = shared
        separator = /
        prefix = Shared/%%u/
        location = maildir:%%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%%Lh/Maildir/Shared/%%Ld/%%Ln
        subscriptions = yes
        list = children
    }
root@mybox:~#
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
root@mybox:~# cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
debugger_command =
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
    ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
debug_peer_level = 2
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
biff = no
swap_bangpath = no
allow_percent_hack = no
allow_min_user = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_protocols = all
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/tls.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/tls.key.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/tls.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
enable_long_queue_ids = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre
smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_unlisted_sender
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient
    reject_unlisted_recipient
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12340
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
enable_original_recipient = no
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_alias_domains =
myhostname = .com
myorigin = toknowl.com
mydomain = toknowl.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]
mydestination = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
message_size_limit = 15728640
recipient_delimiter = +
show_user_unknown_table_name = no
compatibility_level = 2
transport_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_maillist.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
relay_domains =
    $mydestination
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
sender_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
postscreen_greet_action = drop
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
    zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
    b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mlmmj_destination_recipient_limit = 1
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
root@mybox:~#
```

dovecot debug logs

```
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib01_acl_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib10_quota_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib15_notify_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mail_log_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Started userdb lookup
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Connecting
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb (pid=5754,uid=0): Client connected (fd=14)
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): auth USER input: jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Finished userdb lookup (username=jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0)
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:~/Maildir
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule=*:bytes=0
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Effective uid=2000, gid=2000, home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota root: name=user backend=dict args=:proxy::quotadict
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota rule: root=user mailbox=* bytes=0 messages=0
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota warning: bytes=0 (100%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 100 jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota warning: bytes=0 (95%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 95 jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota warning: bytes=0 (90%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 90 jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota warning: bytes=0 (85%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 85 jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Quota grace: root=user bytes=0 (10%)
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: quota-dict: user=jeremy@toknowl.com, uri=proxy::quotadict, noenforcing=0
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Namespace : type=private, prefix=, sep=/, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:~/Maildir
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: maildir++: root=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30//Maildir, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30//Maildir, alt=
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: initializing backend with data: vfile
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: acl username = jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: owner = 1
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl vfile: Global ACLs disabled
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: Namespace : type=shared, prefix=Shared/%u/, sep=/, inbox=no, hidden=no, list=children, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%Lh/Maildir/Shared/%Ld/%Ln
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: shared: root=/run/dovecot, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: initializing backend with data: vfile
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: acl username = jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl: owner = 0
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: acl vfile: Global ACLs disabled
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: quota_over_script unset - skipping
Sep 19 21:19:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5927><VdIAKvTcKGMnFwAAicCTaQ>: Debug: dict(proxy)<jeremy@toknowl.com>: Waiting for dict to finish pending operations
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib01_acl_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib10_quota_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib15_notify_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mail_log_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:19:49 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Started userdb lookup
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Connecting
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb (pid=5754,uid=0): Client connected (fd=9)
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): auth USER input: jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Finished userdb lookup (username=jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0)
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:~/Maildir
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:19:50 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5944><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule=*:bytes=0
Sep 19 21:20:48 mybox dovecot: quota-status(5927): Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb (pid=5754,uid=0): Disconnected: Connection closed (fd=14)
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib01_acl_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib10_quota_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib15_notify_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mail_log_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Started userdb lookup
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Connecting
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/run/dovecot/auth-userdb (pid=5754,uid=0): Client connected (fd=9)
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): auth USER input: jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(jeremy@toknowl.com): Finished userdb lookup (username=jeremy@toknowl.com master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com home=/var/vmail/vmail1/toknowl.com/j/e/r/jeremy-2022.09.17.03.05.30/ mail=maildir:~/Maildir quota_rule=*:bytes=0)
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:~/Maildir
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/master_user=jeremy@toknowl.com
Sep 19 21:20:57 mybox dovecot: lda(jeremy@toknowl.com)<5986><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule=*:bytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the issue within the lda debug logs.

```
Operation not permitted (This binary should probably be called with process group set to 2000 instead of 1003(vmail))
```

did a little

```
usermod -u 2000 vmail
grep 2000 /etc/group
```

restarted everything and I got mail.